# Limit of $\sqrt[10]{n^{10} + 8n^9} - n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ using two "standard" limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I must use the two standard limits $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{\alpha_n}-1}{\alpha_n} = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(1+\beta_n)}{\beta_n} = 1$ if  $\alpha_n, \beta_n \rightarrow 0$ so multiplying by conjugate approach won't work.

My attempt:

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sqrt[10]{n^{10} + 8n^9} - n) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{\ln(\sqrt[10]{n^{10} + 8n^9} - n)} = e^{\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\ln(\sqrt[10]{n^{10} + 8n^9} - n))}$

I am not sure how to proceed further. Any help/hints will be appreciated.

Comment: $n\left(1+\frac8n\right)^{1/10}-n=n\left(1+\frac8{10n}+\cdots\right)-n\to\frac8{10}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have

$$\sqrt[10]{n^{10}+8n^9}-n=e^{\log(\sqrt[10]{n^{10}+8n^{9}}) }-n\ne e^{\log(\sqrt[10]{n^{10}+8n^{9}}-n) }$$

Second, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\alpha_n}-1}{\alpha_n}=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+\beta_n)}{\beta_n}=1$ for $\alpha_n\to 0$ and $\beta_n\to 0$, respectively.

So, how shall we proceed?

Let's first write $\sqrt[10]{n^{10}+8n^9}-n$ as

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt[10]{n^{10}+8n^9}-n&=n\left(\sqrt[10]{1+\frac8n}-1\right)\\\\
&=n\left(e^{\frac1{10}\log\left(1+\frac8n\right)}-1\right)\\\\
&=n\left(\frac{e^{\frac1{10}\log\left(1+\frac8n\right)}-1}{\frac1{10}\log\left(1+\frac8n\right)}\right)\times \left(\frac{\frac1{10}\log\left(1+\frac8n\right)}{\frac8n}\right)\times\left(\frac8n\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sqrt[10]{n^{10} + 8n^9} - n)=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}n \frac{\sqrt[10]{1+\frac{8}{n}}-1}{\frac{8}{n}}\cdot\frac{8}{n}=\frac{8}{10}$$
Using, for $x \to 0$
$$\frac{e^{\alpha \ln (1+x)}-1}{\alpha \ln (1+x)}\cdot \frac{\alpha \ln (1+x)}{x}=\frac{e^{\alpha \ln (1+x)}-1}{x}=\frac{(1+x)^\alpha-1}{x}\to \alpha$$

Comment: This doesn't use the two "standard limits" that the OP states "must" be used.

Comment: @Mark Viola. In last line is exactly using of them. No?

Comment: How does your $x$ and $\alpha$ relate to the first expression you wrote?  I know the answer, but you might wish to make this explicit as I have done in my posted solution.

Comment: @Mark Viola. Do you think, that leaving such details for OP is more pedagogical? I added an exact transition from the "mast" limits, to limit used, but, I think, to connect this last one(i.e. $x$ and $\alpha$) with the first line in my answer should be leaved to OP, since it's better for him/her/self.

Comment: But the OP already has those "standard" limits in the posted question.

Comment: I think you did not understand me - I'm not talking about the fact that there are two standard limits in the question. I pointed out exactly how to get the new result from them (last line), which simply solves the question posed (first line). Leave receiving from the last line first, I think  is better for OP. Maybe, he will solve it himself or he will have questions that I can discuss with him and help get a solution himself. Hope now everything is clear.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\sqrt[10]{n^{10} + 8n^9} - n)=n\left(\sqrt[10]{1+\frac{8}{n}}-1\right) $$
$$\sqrt[10]{1+\frac{8}{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 8^k \binom{\frac{1}{10}}{k}\frac 1{n^k}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 8^k \binom{\frac{1}{10}}{k}\frac 1{n^k}$$
$$n\left(\sqrt[10]{1+\frac{8}{n}}-1\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 8^k \binom{\frac{1}{10}}{k}\frac 1{n^{k-1}}=\frac{4}{5}-\frac{72}{25 n}+\cdots $$